# Apache redirect with GET variables

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect all requests to a subfolder on down on a site. So:

```
http://thesite.com/oldfolder/whatever/anything.php?getvar_stuff
```

goes to

```
http://thesite.com/newfolder/
```

If I use the following .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder http://thesite.com/newfolder/
```

.. the URL that returns is:

```
http://thesite.com/newfolder/?getvar_stuff
```

Don't want the "post_stuff", so I change the rewrite line to:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder http://thesite.com/newfolder/?
```

.. the URL that returns is:

```
http://thesite.com/newfolder/?
```

Which is better, but I'd still love to lose that question mark. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the best way to do this is not using Redirect, but rather Rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://thesite.com/newfolder/? [R=301,L]
```